# Mysql use join type `All` instead of "eq_ref" and slows down the query

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

EF generate large query.
For join `User` table with `Account`, mysql use type 'all', when join `User` and `Account` tables.
Query time - 4.625 sec / 0.000 sec

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | p | NULL | ref | IX_DT_CompanyId , IX_DT_UserId | IX_DT_CompanyId | 5 | const | 359430 | 5.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | PRIMARY | p0 | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY ,IX_Users_EmailId | PRIMARY | 4 | db.p.UserId | 1 | 50.00 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | user.Email | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | db.p0.EmailId | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY | p1 | NULL | ALL | IX_UserAccounts_UserId | NULL | NULL | NULL | 31 | 17.36 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |
| 1 | PRIMARY | p2 | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | db.p1.CompanyId | 1 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | usrAcc.Role | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY ,idx_roles_Id | PRIMARY | 4 | db.p1.RoleId | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 1 | PRIMARY | p3 | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY ,idx_OrgCmps_Id | PRIMARY | 4 | db.p1.OrgCmpId | 1 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | p4 | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | db.p1.CompanyId | 1 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | p5 | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_OrgCmps_Id | PRIMARY | 4 | db.p4.OrgCmpId | 1 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | p8 | NULL | ref | IX_Emails_EmailId | IX_Emails_EmailId | 8 | db.user.Email.Id | 3 | 50.00 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | p7 | NULL | ref | IX_Emails_EmailId, IX_Emails_CompanyId | IX_Emails_EmailId | 8 | db.user.Email.Id | 3 | 23.68 | Using where |

Table `account` contain more 30 records

If i force set index for joining tables (like `FORCE INDEX for join (`IX_UserAccounts_UserId`)` ) - mysql use type `all` for join table `Roles` ('usrAcc.Role').
after i use force index everywhere - duration time 0.187 sec ( origin query 4.625 sec ).
For avoiding full table scans I try use

1. ANALYZE TABLE - in result, if run `explain` - no type all, but, after run my large query, `explain` show type `all` and query slow
2. set max_seeks_for_key=1000 - nothing happen
   I can't use `force index` in app, because write on c# (entity framework )
   I use - mysql Ver 8.0.28 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions and your index definitions as well as the output of EXPLAIN. It will also help to see the query, but in your case it is probably long and complex. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Please provide the query itself.